# Scala regex, how to fix

Tags: regex, scala

here is my code:

```
object test extends App {

  private val PLAYER_REGEX = """[\s\S]*(?:<td class="align-middle plus-size"> <s class="text-muted">|<td class="align-middle plus-size">)(.*)(?:</s> </td></tr>|</td></tr>)""".r
  val str ="""<td class="align-middle plus-size"> <s class="text-muted">first</s> </td></tr>"""
  val str2 ="""<td class="align-middle plus-size">second</td></tr>"""

  private def find(str:String) = {
    PLAYER_REGEX.findFirstMatchIn(str) match {
      case Some(data) => data.group(1).trim
      case None => "Not found"
    }
  }
  println(find(str))
  println(find(str2))
}
```

And Output is

```
first</s>
second
```

My question is - why those redundant

```
</s>
```

in first case? I thought that

```
(?:</s> </td></tr>|</td></tr>)
```

should select first occurence

```
</s> </td></tr>
```

but looks like it select

```
</td></tr>???
```

Off course I can trim it, but it looks ugly.
If you can provide another regex I'll also will be glad:)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5344058...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `why those redundant in first case?` ? The only redundancy I see is in the pattern, since `(?:</s> </td></tr>|</td></tr>)  ` could be written `(?:(?:</s> )?</td></tr>)`

Comment: hi, Aaron. It should return just "first" not "first</s>". At least I tried to do exactly that:)

Comment: (?:(?:</s> )</td></tr>)  works for first case, but not for second:)

Comment: redundancy = multiple occurences of something that would work alone ;) You're getting this result because the previous `.*` being greedy will match up to the end of the string, then backtrack until the next token (the discussed group) matches. It matches "without the </s>" before it backtracks up to the `</s>`

Comment: @AndreiMarkhel I missed a `?` after the nested group, sorry (ninja-edited !). It won't solve your problem anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by this greedy quantifier beforehand:

```
…(.*)…
```

Instead, use the lazy version:

```
…(.*?)…
```

Comment: I believe it's the following `(.*)` that greedily captures too much (check the displayed group). But yeah there would be a problem there too

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. In that case I can't remove [\s\S]*  because I simplified a bit, and whole expression is quite bigger, I just extracted part that not works. I can provide whole expression, off course, but I think it will only add complexity

Comment: @AndreiMarkhel ah, okay.

Comment: Yeah, it did the trick. I mean "(.*?)". Thank you very much! As well to Aaron!